# Magento-How to get product id of simple product at configurable product

Tags: php, magento, cart, configurable-product

Magento : 1.9.2.

I am working on a client requirement which need the quantity box for configurable product attributes like Color,Size (This product attributes are from associated simple products) for ordering bulk. Since I am new to magento, I dont know how to achieve this. Please see the below screen shot.

[image: Each attribute will have quantity box]

So far I have coded at view.phtml file as below and get the design as like the image.

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
$attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributes($_product);

foreach($attributes as $att): 

        $pAtt=$att->getProductAttribute();
        $allProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
```

But anybody help me to get the product Id of filled quantity box to add to cart. How to achieve this?